Can you use multinomial distribution to analyze games like Stellaris?
The way Stellaris works is that its AI operates off a script: when the AI is evaluating what to do, it will choose its course of action randomly, with the probability of a certain action being determined in the game's script. For example, here's the script the AI uses when evaluating whether it should build a corvette, which is the cheapest and smallest ship type.
ai_ship_data = {
        fraction = {
            base = 0
            modifier = {
                add = 15
                uses_standard_ship_sizes = yes
            }
            modifier = {
                factor = 1.5
                is_hive_empire = yes
            }
            modifier = {
                factor = 1.25
                NOT = { is_preferred_weapons = weapon_type_explosive }
            }
            modifier = {
                factor = 0.75
                is_preferred_weapons = weapon_type_strike_craft
                has_technology = tech_destroyers
            }
            modifier = {
                factor = 1.5
                has_valid_ai_personality = yes
                OR = {
                    has_ai_personality = ruthless_capitalists #doing it cheap, or something
                    has_ai_personality = hegemonic_imperialists
                }
            }

What I want to do is use multinomial distribution to calculate the fraction of ships that I should expect to see in a given size fleet. There's an added level of complexity here that certain ship sizes take up a larger fraction of a fleet's size limit (in the context of multinomial distribution, when a trial gives a certain result, it reduces your number of remaining trials by an amount greater than one). Can multinomial distribution take this into account, and can I apply it to other aspects of the game, like determining how many empires I need to generate to get a specific randomly generated empire?

UPDATE: Upon the request of a commenter, I've provided some additional clarification. I have attached a screenshot of Stellaris' fleet manager window to add some visual clarity. To provide further explanation, a given ship type in Stellaris has a certain "size," and all fleets are limited in the total size of the ships within them, referred to in-game as the command limit. Corvettes and frigates have a size of 1, destroyers of 2, cruisers of 4, battleships of 8, and titans of 16. You can add any number of ships you want to a fleet via the fleet manager window, so long as the ships' total size remains under the command limit.
What I want to know here is, given a certain probability p that the AI will add t ship to a fleet, how many of each ship type should I expect to see for a given overall size limit? The methods I have found all work great when the ship's size is equal to 1, but in Stellaris, this is not the case, and I'm looking for a method that can take into account ship sizes that are NOT equal to 1.

It feels like the reinforcement learning techniques would behave much better in this case. Why do you need to use static methods, though?

Sadly there is no general solution to your problem, you could technically compute all the possible configuration and their probabilities or just simulate the process and go with the empirical distribution.
Let say there are $n$ different types of ships $t_1, \dots , t_n$. Each one of them has a size $s_1, \dots, s_n$ and when the AI decides to build a ship it chooses at random and the type $t_i$ has a probability $p_i$ to be chosen. $C$ is the maximum size of the fleet.
On a first approximation, the proportion of the resulting fleet of type $t_i$ is $p_i$ and it follows a multinomial distribution Multi($\frac{C}{s\cdot p}, p$). where $s\cdot p = \sum_{i=1}^n s_i p_i$ is the average size of a ship. Of course $\frac{C}{s\cdot p}$ not being an integer you should take the integer part.
Technical details ahead :
We will suppose the AI builds the its fleet sequentially, that means it chooses between the available types of ships one with each type having a probability $p_i$ to be chosen.
There are to possible ways the AI decides the fleet is finished :

It tries to build a ship and the capacity is excedeed and decides to stop there.
It tries to build a ship, if it exceeds the capacity it cancels it and tries again. It stops once it reached exactly the capacity.

The first case is a little bit easier, but from what I've understood, it more likely to be the second case (notice that the second case will yield the same result as changing the probability to ignore all the ships that are too large).
We model this as follow :
$S_k = (S_k^1, \dots, S_k^n)$ is the composition of the fleet after $t$ iterations of ship creations, where $S_t^i$ is the number of ships of type $t_i$.
The size of the fleet after $k$ iterations is equal to $S_k \cdot s = \sum_{i=1}^n S_k^i s_i$.
$(S_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Markov Chain, with the following increments :
$$S_{k+1} = \begin{cases}S_k + X_k \quad \text{if }(S_k+X_k)\cdot s \leq C \\
S_k \quad\quad\quad\;\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
where $X_k = e_i$ with probability $p_i$ and $e_i = (0,\dots,0, 1, 0, \dots, 0)$ is the vector with a 1 in the $i$-th component. Adding $e_i$ means we added a ship of type $t_i$ to our fleet.
Let $\|s\|_\infty = \max_{1\leq i\leq n} s_i$ the size of the largest ship.
Notice that if $S_k \cdot s \leq C-\|s\|_\infty$ we do not need to check if we can build the next ship. We denote by $T$ the iteration where the fleet becomes strictly larger than $C-\|s\|_\infty$. $T$ is what we call a stopping time.
Conditionally on $T$ (we know the number of ships in the fleet when we surpassed $C-\|s\|_\infty$), the fleet follows the distribution Multi$(T, p)$.
Suppose you know the distribution of $(T,S_T \cdot s)$ (the size of the fleet takes its values between $C - \|s\|_\infty +1$ and $C$). You can condition on this value, then keep building your fleet but only with the ships that are small enough, this is recursive but I don't know any way of solving it.
There is a theorem that says that $\mathbb{E}[S_T \cdot s] = \mathbb{E}[X_1 \cdot s]\mathbb{E}[T]$ and on first approximation, we can say that $T\approx \mathbb{E}[T]$ and $\mathbb{E}[S_T \cdot s] \approx C$ thus $T\approx \frac{C}{s\cdot p}$ and the fleet has distribution $Multi( \frac{C}{s\cdot p}, p)$.
From a rule of thumb, you can expect there is proportion slightly larger than $p_i$ for ships of small size (because they will be used to complete the fleet at the end) and slightly smaller for ships of high size (because they cannot be build at the end).

I apologize if I was unclear. I've attached a screenshot of the in-game fleet manager window and provided additional context in the original post, let me know if you need more clarification.
